# Perl XML DOM XPATH : Insert Values Using Perl

Tags: xml, perl, dom

I'm new to Perl XML:DOM XML:XPath (Have to use these only.)
How to insert values to the following xml file:
Need to Insert 1010, 1011 before 1020 in BadgeID (Using only Perl DOM & XPath) 
Tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::DOM;
use XML::XPath;

my $mainFile = "badgelist.xml";
$xpmain = eval { XML::XPath->new( filename => $mainFile ); };

my $root = $main->getDocumentElement(); 
    my @list = $root->getElementsByTagName('Name');
    foreach my $key ( @list ) {
        if( $key->getFirstChild->getData eq 'Home' ) {

           $root->insertBefore($newparam, $genericMap);
           # Insert 1005, 1006 and 1007 before 1008

        }
    }



<Badge-Lists>
                <List>
                        <Name>Home</Name>
                        <Badges>
                                        <BadgeID>1001</BadgeID>
                                        <BadgeID>1008</BadgeID>
                                        <BadgeID>1020</BadgeID>
                        </Badges>
                </List> 

                <List>
                        <Name>Office</Name>
                        <Badges>
                                        <BadgeID>5001</BadgeID>
                                        <BadgeID>5012</BadgeID>
                                        <BadgeID>5040</BadgeID>
                        </Badges>
                </List>                 
</Badge-Lists>
```

Comment: Perl module names have two colons `::`, not one. Have you started working on this and are stuck, or do you not know how to start?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us some code. Why do you think you have to use those specific modules?

Comment: Your XML is not valid. It doesn't have a closing tag.

Comment: Also, your is incomplete. It doesn't compile. Not even with `strict` turned off.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. I managed to do that just by reading the documentation of XML::DOM.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::DOM;

my $parser = XML::DOM::Parser->new;
my $doc    = $parser->parse(*DATA);

# the documentation of XML::DOM is extensive, but I'm not familiar with it,
# so we just use good old Perl to find the right element
my ($badge_1020) = grep { $_->getFirstChild->getNodeValue eq '1020' ? $_ : () }
    $doc->getElementsByTagName('BadgeID');

# we need the parent to insert new nodes later
my $badges = $badge_1020->getParentNode;

foreach my $value ( 1010, 1011 ) {
    # create a new element based on our badge
    my $node = $badge_1020->cloneNode(1);

    # change the text
    $node->getFirstChild->setNodeValue($value);

    # put it into the Badges before the 1020 one
    $badges->insertBefore( $node, $badge_1020 );
}

print $doc->toString;

__DATA__
<Badge-Lists>
                <List>
                        <Name>Home</Name>
                        <Badges>
                                        <BadgeID>1001</BadgeID>
                                        <BadgeID>1008</BadgeID>
                                        <BadgeID>1020</BadgeID>
                        </Badges>
                </List>

                <List>
                        <Name>Office</Name>
                        <Badges>
                                        <BadgeID>5001</BadgeID>
                                        <BadgeID>5012</BadgeID>
                                        <BadgeID>5040</BadgeID>
                        </Badges>
                </List>
</Badge-Lists>
```

It will output:

```
<Badge-Lists>
                <List>
                        <Name>Home</Name>
                        <Badges>
                                        <BadgeID>1001</BadgeID>
                                        <BadgeID>1008</BadgeID>
                                        <BadgeID>1010</BadgeID><BadgeID>1011</BadgeID><BadgeID>1020</BadgeID>
                        </Badges>
                </List>

                <List>
                        <Name>Office</Name>
                        <Badges>
                                        <BadgeID>5001</BadgeID>
                                        <BadgeID>5012</BadgeID>
                                        <BadgeID>5040</BadgeID>
                        </Badges>
                </List>
</Badge-Lists>
```